# Deleting Index of leading 0s in bit array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to delete the leading 0's for a bit array I created out of a list. What I am trying to do is:

```
while binPayload[0] == 0:
    del binPayload[0]
```

However the interrupter is throwing:

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check that the list is not empty each time before indexing it. Since [an empty list is considered false](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), you can simply do:

```
while binPayload and binPayload[0] == 0:
    del binPayload[0]
```

Comment: still throwing the same error. I am trying to populate it for example with 00001111 so I should in fact be left with 1111.

Comment: What do you get if you put `print binPayload` just before the while statement? Or `print(binPayload)` for python 3 obviously.

Comment: Ha! I found the error. I was doing the same thing for another list which was denominator and I was also del binPayload[0]. Found that out because of print statement, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import itertools as it
a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
list(it.dropwhile(lambda x: x == 0, a))
=> [1, 1, 1, 1]
```